# sql query with max

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

```
SELECT  MATCH_ID ,
        PLAYER_ID ,
        COUNT(PLAYER_ID) AS TOTAL
FROM    MATCH_RESULTS
GROUP BY MATCH_ID ,
        PLAYER_ID
```

I want to know which player was played more on the matches
I'm tring to use `MAX(COUNT(PLAYER_ID))` but it doesn't allow me.
Can someone think for an answer please?

Comment: Use one other outer query to find the MAX.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want which player has the most match_IDs you can use:

```
SELECT  PLAYER_ID ,
        COUNT(PLAYER_ID) AS MatchCount
FROM    MATCH_RESULTS
GROUP BY PLAYER_ID
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an updated answer that will return *all* players having the maximum matches played:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/16586/9

```
;with cte as (
  SELECT player_id, count(1) as matchesPlayed
  from match_results
  group by player_id
)
select *
from cte
where matchesPlayed = (select max(matchesPlayed) from cte)
```

the above method is called a common table expression 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175972.aspx

There are probably plenty of other ways to arrive at the result as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
SELECT TOP 1
    MATCH_ID,
    PLAYER_ID,
    COUNT(*)
FROM MATCH_RESULTS
GROUP BY MATCH_ID,PLAYER_ID
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
```

Answer (score -1):

If you only want the top player, try this:

```
SELECT PLAYER_ID, COUNT(1) AS TOTAL 
FROM MATCH_RESULTS 
GROUP BY PLAYER_ID
ORDER BY COUNT(1) DESC
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: Did this answers the Question or will it work in `SQL SERVER`

Comment: syntax above only works in mysql. in sql server you'll need to select top 1. See Kritner's solution. It should work.

Answer (score -1):

You have to select the most as the first result of:

```
SELECT PLAYER_ID, COUNT(*) as TOTAL
FROM MATCH_RESULTS 
GROUP BY PLAYER_ID
ORDER BY TOTAL DESC
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/4e300/3

Comment: Question is tagged with `SQL SERVER`